# center an element within a dynamic height and width parent

Tags: html, css

```
<div><span>A</span></div>
```

Imagine above is a button of a keyboard. The challenge is the div's width and height is dynamic because I want it to be responsive. So how can I center the span? I can do `postion:relative` and use top to adjust it to the center but since the width and height is dynamic I can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use table and table-cell then text-align center and vertical-align middle.

```
div {
    display: table;
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}
span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<div><span>A</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the trick I've performed many times:

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
div span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Note that you may need to add `-webkit-` or other vendor prefixes on `transform` to work on some older browsers.

This works because `left` and `top` percentage values are relative to the parent element while `transform` is relative to the selected element itself.

Comment: have you tried this, the span go way down to the right in my case.

Comment: @MaySun wait a sec, I'm trying on fiddle.

Comment: @MaySun Answer edited, seems this can be only be done on absolute position element.  You may try the new answer using table too. But I personally don't like using `display:table`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Flexbox layout feature,just add:

```
 div{
     display:flex; 
     flex-direction: row; 
     flex-wrap: wrap; 
     align-items: center; 
     justify-content: center;
 }
```

Run the demo

```css
div{
     display:flex; 
     flex-direction: row; 
     flex-wrap: wrap; 
     align-items: center; 
     justify-content: center;
 }
.border{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.h1{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
.h2{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border h1"><span>A</span></div>
<div class="border h2"><span>A</span></div>
```

To fix the gap among the browsers, you should add the browser's unique prefix to the property name:

```
 div{
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -moz-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row; 
     flex-wrap: wrap; 
     align-items: center; 
     justify-content: center;
 }
```

#### see

- [CanIUse Flex](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)
- [Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)